# Find all tables without a certain column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I've seen lots of questions about finding all tables with a specific column name. However, I'm trying to find all tables WITHOUT a specific column. (In this case, EndDate). Is there a more elegant solution than just finding all the tables with that column, and comparing it to the list of all tables?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT
    table_name
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
WHERE
    T.TABLE_CATALOG = 'MyDB' AND
    T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        WHERE
            C.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG AND
            C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
            C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME AND
            C.COLUMN_NAME = 'EndDate')
```

Comment: You should consider to add `T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND` right before `NOT EXISTS (` - this will ensure that the result list only contains tables and not views.

Comment: @Mötz Thanks for the suggestion. I've added that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, It's standard SQL (and will work for almost every platform)

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
EXCEPT
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'EndDate'
```

Just as you suggested, you can't really get anything that's simpler than this.

Comment: You need to account for catalog and schema as well

Comment: True Tom (+1 to your solution)

Comment: @Tom H - I dont think you need to account for Catalog, as this query can only be run against one... perhaps im wrong.

Comment: At worst, the Catalog checking does no harm. But the schema name needs to be checked for sure.

Comment: Yes, in SQL Server the catalog is irrelevant since INFORMATION_SCHEMA only applies to the current database (which, for SQL Server, is a catalog). I don't know about other RDBMSs though and as Michael says, you definitely need to account for schema.

Comment: Unfortunately, `EXCEPT` is not supported by MySQL (little surprising).  But I'm upvoting, because you have a good idea here.  The same exact effect can be accomplished by `UNION ALL` on a list of "all tables" + a "list of tables with the field", and selecting results `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`.  Would not have thought of this approach otherwise, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
   WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA 
  AND c.COLUMN_NAME='EndDate')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have many more schemas and tables than I really ought to, so I need an optimized version that runs in a second.

*Why not get all tables, then get all tables with the field, `UNION ALL` these results, and just show the table names where `HAVING COUNT(table_name) = 1`?*  That's just what I did.

Notice the two vars to change below: `YourSchemaHere` and `YourFieldHere`.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(TABLE_NAME) FROM (
    (SELECT DISTINCT c1.TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1
        WHERE c1.Table_Schema = "YourSchemaHere")
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT DISTINCT c2.TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2
        WHERE c2.Table_Schema = "YourSchemaHere" AND
        c2.Column_Name = "YourFieldHere")
) x GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(TABLE_NAME) = 1;
```

Online Demo at SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/791dde/1/0

Explanation of my approach:

- Get all tables with : `SELECT DISTINCT c1.TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1 WHERE c1.Table_Schema = "YourSchemaHere"`
- Get all tables with column : `SELECT DISTINCT c2.TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2 WHERE c2.Table_Schema = "YourSchemaHere" AND c2.Column_Name = "YourFieldHere"`
- `UNION ALL` these two results.
- Items in resulting list will be duplicated if they have the column, but only appear once if they do not.
- Select only those without the field:`HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`